# Find sub string position from the end of string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query which finds the position of sub string.

```
select position('-' || lower('i') in lower('GFT-iMB5-i'))
```

(this is an example it actually uses function variables to replace the strings)

This return `4`

In a nut shell I want it to begin from the end of the string and not from the start.
meaning I want to get: `9`

How can I do that?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/D7FF158337303A419CF4A183F48302D603525D2C%40hdsmsx411.amr.corp.intel.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method is to reverse the values and do comparison that way:

```
select length('GFT-iMB5-i') - position(reverse('-' || lower('i')) in reverse(lower('GFT-iMB5-i')))
```

Comment: Almost, except `position` returns `0` when the searched substring not found. That could be emulated with f.ex. `length(...) - coalesce(nullif(position(...), 0), length(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

The post by @Gordon Linoff assumes that the last '-' searched for follows the char 'i'. But if this is generic need, the below might be helpful.

However the reverse function suggested by Gordon helps

```
with TMP as
(select 1 id, 'GFT-iKJ5-c' col1
union
select 2 id, 'GJT-iMB5-bdi' col1
union
select 3 id, 'NDT-iMJ7-ipt' col1
union
select 4 id, 'MDF-iDF-il' col1)

select id, col1, reverse(substring(trim(reverse(col1)), 1, position('-' in trim(reverse(col1))) - 1)) last_str
from TMP
;
```